# Issues with hosting my local Typo3 website on IONOS

Tags: typo3, hosting, ionos

I made a local Typo3 12.4.9 website and created a GitHub repository.
Now I want to host it with IONOS. Cloning the repository with SSH worked, but now I don't know what to do next.
I cant install composer `Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r`

The IONOS support cant help me and I didnt find a documentation about it. I hope you can help me. Thanks in adance.

Edit: Added `/usr/bin/php8.0-cli` before the command. Now I can install composer and Typo3. But that brings me to the next problem:

Usually the IONOS webspace is directed to the project (e.g. /clickandbuilds/website) which includes the files that are in my public directory and few more.
This is my project: [image]

Second picture is the typical Typo3 website from ionos after installing composer. [image]

Where do I have to link the web space?

Comment: Can you please add what command you are trying to execute and how and where?

Answer (score 0):

Install composer stuff locally. And then copy it (rsync) to the server. Then use TYPO3 commandline Tools for db Update Schema, flushing caches and more.

Comment: I added everything with git clone. This isnt the problem. I dont know how to configure the ionos webspace. I tried portfolio and portfolio/public but got the 404 not found error.

Comment: If your TYPO3 installation is in the portfolio folder, then the `portfolio/public` folder is the target for the domain. To test this, you can create a simple html file, e.g. `test.html` in the `portfoli/public` folder and try open that file in the browser. `https://yourdomain.de/test.html` Now you see the problem is about missing files or folders in your installation or is about the domain routing.